# Is it the right place to use mocking in Unit test?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing, mocking

The question is at the bottom, a little context first:

I have two nested factories, let's say `Team` and `Player`. Let's say there's a business rule is that there must be created 5 players with number 0 and name "Bot" upon team creation (and added to this team).

I have two factories:

```
public class PlayerFactory : IPlayerFactory
{
    public IPlayer Create(int number, string name)
    {
        return new Player(number, name);
    }
}

public class TeamFactory : ITeamFactory
{
    private IPlayerFactory PlayerFactory { get; }

    public TeamFactory(IPlayerFactory playerFactory)
    {
        PlayerFactory = playerFactory;
    }

    public ITeam Create(int height, int width)
    {
        // ... do some operations to create players
        List<IPlayer> players = ...
        return new Team(players);
    }
}
```

so far, so good. Now.. I want to create tests (ok, technically I created tests first):

```
[TestFixture]
public class PlayerFactoryTests
{
    [Test]
    public void CreatePlayerNumberTest()
    {
        IPlayerFactory playerFactory = new PlayerFactory();
        IPlayer player = playerFactory.Create(2, "");
        Assert.AreEqual(2, player.Number);
    }

    [Test]
    public void CreatePlayerNameTest()
    {
        IPlayerFactory playerFactory = new PlayerFactory();
        IPlayer player = playerFactory.Create(2, "John");
        Assert.AreEqual("John", player.Name);
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class TeamFactoryTests
{
    [Test]
    public void CreateTeamTest()
    {
        IPlayerFactory playerFactory = new PlayerFactory();
        ITeamFactory teamFactory = new TeamFactory(playerFactory);

        ITeam team = teamFactory.Create(); 
    }
}
```

The question is:

**Should I mock `IPlayerFactory` in `CreateTeamTest` test?**
If yes, How should I do that?

EDIT:

```
public class Player : IPlayer
{
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Player(int num)
    {
        PlayerId = num;
        Name = "";
    }
}



public ITeam Create(int number)
{
    IPlayer[] players = new IPlayer[number];

    for (int i = 0; i < players.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        players[i] = PlayerFactory.Create(i);
    }
    return new Team(players);
}
```

Comment: Yes.. you should create mock of `IPlayerFactory` in that test. You can explore mocking frameworks like `RhinoMock` and `Moq`.

Comment: You have to mock IPlayerFactory if it is being used int the create method, because you won't be able properly to assert results, otherwise just pass null

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to assert in the test.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya So, is it a rule that there must be only one "new" pre one test? to create an object that will be tested?

Comment: @Nkosi I want to test if the Team is created properly - `Create` method

Comment: @LouisaBickley if there are no unintended side effect of using the actual implementation of the dependency then there is no need to mock it. Given your simplified example `IPlayerFactory` does not need to be mocked. It can be mocked but doesn't have to be mocked. If however `IPlayerFactory` was making calls to an external resource that would hinder the unit test then that would be a reason to mock the factory so that the dependent class under test can be exercised in isolation to external factors.

Comment: @LouisaBickley show more of the team factory method under test so as to get a more definitive answer as to whether and how you should mock the dependency as it relates to this particular scenario.

Comment: @Nkosi so, the factory is very simple. Don't treat "Team" and "Players" as actual names.. Pleas, have a look at my edit